# How to show a popup box after registration?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, popup

I'd like to show a popup box after a member has registered, similar to [jQuery popup](http://www.jquerypopup.com/documentation.php).
I want to include a button inside the popup box so I cannot use the alert function.

Here is my current code:

```
if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'])
{
    echo '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'].'</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community.  Please do remember to select an answer to your question by clicking the checkbox on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to use a dynamic scripting language like javascript.  Essentially set the visibility of the Div when the user clicks a button.

You will also need to add an id to the div:

```
echo '<div class="success" id="success">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'].'</div>';
```

Essentially add a link like so:

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:hide(document.getElementById('success'))\">Hide box</a>";
```

Then add the script:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function hide(a){
    a.style.display="none"
}
</script>';
```

That should do it... The end results are something like this:

```
if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']) {
    echo '<div class="success" id="success">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'];
    echo "<a href=\"javascript:hide(document.getElementById('success'))\">Hide box</a>";
    echo '</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']);
}

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    function hide(a){
        a.style.display="none"
    }
    </script>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! can you explain a little bit more about this process? thanks alot!

Comment: Sure just added a little demo.

Comment: thanks for more explanation.
sorry for keep asking...but i m kinda confused of how to implement everything together to work it out.
do i add your lines together and it should work?
million thasnks!!!

Comment: Stephen, thanks for the codes!
it works but its not exactly what i want...now this is closing the lines...but what i want is to have a new window to popup thanks!

Comment: You will need to edit the CSS of the div.  In the head of the page (in between the <head> tags) add something like the following:

`div.success {display: block;
   position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 0; width: 125px;
   padding: 5px; margin: 10px; z-index: 100;}`

more details: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/popups/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do this way.

```
<?php if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
openPopup();// Call popup function
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Noty](http://needim.github.com/noty/#buttons). I believe it is something like you are looking for. However you are going to have to mess around with the source code to do exactly what you what your site to do after the user has registered.

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
  noty({
    text: "Display your message HERE", 
    buttons: [
      {type: 'button green', text: 'Enter your text for the button HERE', click: function($noty) {

          $noty.close();

          **doSomethingHere()**
        }
      },
      {type: 'button pink', text: 'Enter your text for the button HERE', click: function($noty) {
          $noty.close();

          **doSomethingHere()**
        }
      }
      ],
    closable: false,
    timeout: false
  });
  return false;
});
```

Please let me know if you need help with this if you plan on using it. You must include the source code in your site before this is able to function. Click [here](http://needim.github.com/noty/#installation) for installation help for your site

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! but i have no idea on php coding. how should i include this function into my current codes? thanks so much!

Comment: there is no PHP code necessary for this! It is all done with jQyery - all you have to do is put the script link on your page like so: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.noty.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.noty.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/noty_theme_default.css"/>`. If you go to http://needim.github.com/noty/ it tells you how to do everything. it even has demos to show you how it works.

Comment: thanks for the help! but i hope the box would appear after the form is submitted. how can noty work with that? thanks!!

Comment: notice i just changed my answer so that instead of noty showing up after you click on something it will appear after the form has been submitted using the `$('#form').submit(function(){ });`

Comment: Hi Noah thanks for the code! but how is this going to incorporate into my current codes? thanks alot!!

Comment: your question was to have a popup show after a form was submitted was it not?

Comment: yes exactly!but i dunno how to incorporate into the above codes

Comment: when the form is submitted there is no need (from what i can see) to use any of the php code that you have in your question. but rather all you have to do is install Noty (by copy and pasting the code on this site: http://needim.github.com/noty/#installation) on your file and then copy and past the code that i have above in `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` and it should be good to go. **Of course you need to edit my code so that it will work according to your needs.**